# How to fill Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) directly in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

is there any way to do the same in VB.NET?

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>()     
{        
     { 2, "This" },    
     { 1, "is" },          
     { 5, "radio" },      
     { 12, "clash" },     
};
```

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318530/is-it-possible-to-initialise-a-new-system-collections-generic-dictionary-with-str
Check jgauffin's answer. Here is an example:
`Dim myDic As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From {{1, "One"}, {2, "Two"}}`. This is only for VB.NET 10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in Marcel's comment above:

```
Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From _
        {{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}}
```